# Pass query from Search bar to results page React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Ive made a search and filtering bar as part of an application im making in React. The current way it works is suggestions appear as you type. However there is no handler for if the user just clicks the submit button. At the moment clicking the submit button will take you to a results page with the query in the page URL.
I would like this to be passed as a state when you click the link. This link could then be displayed in the Results component.
Ive attempted this but im fairly new to React so any help would be appreciated.

Heres the search component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const content = [
    {link: '/review/elden-ring', name: 'Elden\nRing'},
    {link: '/review/', name: 'defg'},
    {link: '/review/', name: 'ghij'},
    {link: '/review/', name: 'jklm'},
]

export default function Search(props) {
    //For storing and setting search input
    const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

    return (
        //Search input
        <div class="flex flex-col z-10">
            <form class="text-black ml-5 py-0.5 lg:py-0 flex border-2 border-gray-400 rounded-md bg-white px-1">
                <input id="searchInput" class="focus:outline-none" type="text" placeholder="Search" value={query} onChange={event => {setQuery(event.target.value)}}/>
                
                <div class="flex mt-1.5"> {/* Flex container to align the icon and bar */}
                    <Link to={{pathname: "/results/" + query, state: {query}}}> {/* Error handler as search is strick */}
                        <button type="submit" onClick={() => setQuery(() => "")}>
                            <svg class="fill-current h-auto w-4 " xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"> {/* ! Font Awesome Pro 6.1.0 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license (Commercial License) Copyright 2022 Fonticons, Inc. */}
                            <path d="M500.3 443.7l-119.7-119.7c27.22-40.41 40.65-90.9 33.46-144.7C401.8 87.79 326.8 13.32 235.2 1.723C99.01-15.51-15.51 99.01 1.724 235.2c11.6 91.64 86.08 166.7 177.6 178.9c53.8 7.189 104.3-6.236 144.7-33.46l119.7 119.7c15.62 15.62 40.95 15.62 56.57 0C515.9 484.7 515.9 459.3 500.3 443.7zM79.1 208c0-70.58 57.42-128 128-128s128 57.42 128 128c0 70.58-57.42 128-128 128S79.1 278.6 79.1 208z" />
                            </svg>
                        </button>
                    </Link>
                </div>
            </form>

            {/* Search Suggestions */}
            <div class="ml-5 px-0.5">
                {/* Query must have length to prevent mapping by default */}
                {query.length > 0 && content.filter((content) => {
                    //If input return object
                    if (query == "") {
                        return content
                    }

                    //If any input characters much object characters return corresponding object
                    else if (content.name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLocaleLowerCase())) {
                        return content
                    }

                })
                //Maps element based on the number of json objects
                .map((content) => {
                    return(
                        <div class="bg-white rounded-sm">
                            <Link to={content.link} onClick={() => setQuery(() => "")}><p>{content.name}</p></Link>
                        </div>
                    );
                })};
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Heres the Results component

```
import *  as React from 'react';

export default function Results(props) {
    return (
        <h1>{props.location.state.query}</h1>
    );
};
```

Routes

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './app.css';
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Header from './components/header/header';
import Footer from './components/footer';
import Error from './components/error';
import Results from './components/results';
import Index from './components/index/index';
import ReviewsPage from './components/reviews/reviewsPage';
import Review from './components/reviews/review';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Index />} />
        <Route path="/reviews" element={<ReviewsPage />} />
        {/* Render review with ID for switch statment */}
        <Route path="/review/:id" element={<Review />} />
        <Route path="/results/:id" element={<Results />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<Error />} />
      </Routes>

      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};
```

Search component import line 30

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Search from './search';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Header() {
  //State to toggle navlinks on small screens
  const [state, setState] = useState(false)

  return (
    <nav className=" w-full bg-red-500 shadow-lg relative max-h-[4.1rem]"> {/* Max height set to avoid search suggestions increasing header size */}
      <div className="flex justify-between py-3.5 w-full px-3 md:w-2/3 md:px-0  m-auto">
        {/* Logo */}
        <Link className="text-2xl font-semibold text-white hover:animate-pulse whitespace-nowrap"  to="/">GAME REVIEWS</Link>

        <div className="flex max-h-[3rem]"> {/* Container to prevent flex effecting both parents container */}
          {/* Links */}
          {!state && (
            <ul id="links" className=" h-40 lg:h-auto flex-col flex lg:flex-row absolute lg:relative mt-10 lg:mt-0 right-0 lg:right-auto px-10 lg:px-0 bg-red-500 rounded-lg lg:rounded-none shadow-sm lg:shadow-none">
              <li className="m-5 lg:my-0 lg:mx-5">
                <Link className="text-2xl text-white border-none hover:border-solid border-b-2 border-white" to="/">Home</Link>
              </li>
              <li className="m-5 lg:my-0 lg:mx-5">
                <Link className="text-2xl text-white border-none hover:border-solid border-b-2 border-white" to="/reviews">Reviews</Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          )}

          {/* Search bar */}
          <Search />

          {/* Hamburger */}
          <div id="hamburger" onClick={() => setState(!state)} className=" space-y-2 ml-5 mt-2 block cursor-pointer lg:hidden">
            <div className="w-6 h-0.5 bg-white"></div>
            <div className="w-6 h-0.5 bg-white"></div>
            <div className="w-6 h-0.5 bg-white"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  )
}
```

Heres an example of what I want to achieve
User searches 'game'

[image]

Upon clicking the icon on the right they should be redirected to my results page. This page should show what they just entered on submit.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want the page results to be shared, you must include on the url the search term something like: [www.yourdomain.com/review/elden-ring](http://www.yourdomain.com/review/elden-ring)

Take a look and you will see that I've defined that the `review` route now expects a parameter. You should use that parameter to check all the data you need to display on the page.

And had to edit the Search component because you're using `class` instead of `className` for styling.

On the `Results` component I use the `useParams` hook to get the url params and show it on the `h1`.  You should use this param as a key to retrieve the actual details of the review of your API.

This is how I'd do (all the logic):

On the App component I define the routes:

```
<Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Search />} />
        <Route path="/review/:query" element={<Results />} />
      </Routes>
```

On the Search component:

```
// Router v6 hook to navigate the user
const navigate = useNavigate();

const queryRef = useRef(null) // Reference to the input

// Navigates the user to reviews/what they've written 
const queryHandler = () => navigate(`/reviews/${queryRef.current.value}`);

return (
<>
   // This is where the user types the query
   <input type='text' ref={queryRef} placeholder='Search' />
   <Icon onClick={queryHandler} /> // This has the onClick to hndle the click
</>
)
```

And on the results component:

```
const params = useParams(); // This retrieves all the params defined for the url 

<h1>{params.query}</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but it doesnt seem for me to display what was entered into the search input on the results page.

Comment: okok I think now I've understood what you want I've updated the answer and codesandbox try now

Comment: Still nothing im afraid. Ill update the post with some visual aid to help.

Comment: `props` is to pass properties to a child component in this case you need to use the `react-router-dom` to send and retrieve params to your component. Take a look: https://en.reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: I have already achieved something similar ill add my routes to the post to clarify.

Comment: I've updated my answer with all the logic I think you should implement. You only need to redirect the user to a page that is `/reviews/query` after clicking one button.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic route in the `Link` component which passes `query` in the URL. And to parse it in `Result` component, you can use `match` props.

To navigate change your `Link` component to

```
<Link to={"/results/" + query} />
```

And to parse the `query` in `Result` component, use

```
<h1>{props.match.params.id}</>
```

Comment: Ive created a similar route im unsure how to get that into the component however. Ive updated the post with my routes.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Check with that

Answer (score 0):

The `query` you're sending in the `history.push()` method must be an `object`. Instead, you are sending a string. Change it to object like below

```
    props.history.push({
       pathname: '/results',
       state: { query }
    });
```

Comment: I have now thankyou, its not made a difference though

Comment: And try changing this `const { query } = props?.location?.state || {}` in the Results component

Comment: If you look at the updated question I have changed that component to a class and tried to access it by ``` {props.location.state.query} ```

Answer (score 0):

For the following route.
localhost:3000/search/?query=ABCD

The following code on load extract the ABCD from query=ABCD and set to the state.

```js
export default function App() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState(() => {
    const q = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    console.log(q.toString());
    return q.get("query") || "";
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Query</h1>
      <h2>{query}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So this way you can extract the info from a route.

Now if you want to know how to move from one page to another

assuming you are using some routing library, look at how you can change the route

```
history.push(`/search/?query={query}`)
```

is a way to use with react router ( ensure you use the useHistory hook for it )

Answer (score 0):

It was far simpler than I thought and something I had done on a different page

Creating a state for the input.
Setting input as the variable in that state (query).
Setting the value as the input using an onClick on the button.
The link then provided the state variable with the route.

```
const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

      <form
        className="text-black ml-5 py-0.5 lg:py-0 flex border-2 border-gray-400 rounded-md bg-white px-1"
      >
        <input
          id="searchInput"
          className="focus:outline-none"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search"
          value={query}
          onChange={(event) => {
            setQuery(event.target.value);
          }}
        />

        {/* Flex container to align the icon and bar */}
        <div className="flex mt-1.5">
          <Link to={{ pathname: "/results/" + query }}>
            <button type="submit" onClick={() => setQuery(() => "")}>
              <svg
                className="fill-current h-auto w-4 "
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                viewBox="0 0 512 512"
              >
                {/* ! Font Awesome Pro 6.1.0 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license (Commercial License) Copyright 2022 Fonticons, Inc. */}
                <path d="M500.3 443.7l-119.7-119.7c27.22-40.41 40.65-90.9 33.46-144.7C401.8 87.79 326.8 13.32 235.2 1.723C99.01-15.51-15.51 99.01 1.724 235.2c11.6 91.64 86.08 166.7 177.6 178.9c53.8 7.189 104.3-6.236 144.7-33.46l119.7 119.7c15.62 15.62 40.95 15.62 56.57 0C515.9 484.7 515.9 459.3 500.3 443.7zM79.1 208c0-70.58 57.42-128 128-128s128 57.42 128 128c0 70.58-57.42 128-128 128S79.1 278.6 79.1 208z" />
              </svg>
            </button>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Then in the route the path is given a variable (id)

```
<Route path="/results/:id" element={<Results />} />
```

This could then be pulled in the results page by useParams.
And assigned to my h1 tag.

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Results(props) {
    const {id} = useParams();

    return (
        <h1>{id}</h1>
    );
};
```

Thank you for everyone help and guidance.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).